# Django User Sessions, Cookies and Timeout

Tags: python, django, session, cookies, django-models

I'm working with a Django application and my current goal is to keep track of the user session with cookies. I have a feeling that, as always, my understanding is a bit off with regards to how I do this.

For starters, I would like to manage *how long* it has been since a user has logged in, that way I can successfully log them out if they haven't visited a new page in "x" hours. I am not sure what exactly is standard (for a social network).

Is this information I store on my server? Do cookies actually have any relevancy here? I've used cookies before to store things like a user's timezone, but I am struggling to deal with how I keep track of the user.

All I currently have in terms of user back end is from the [django.contrib.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) package.

The only thing I really know how to do in terms of "grabbing" the user's info is done by using statements like `if request.user.is_authenticated():` (etc.).

I realize this is somewhat of a complex question, so I will try and narrow it down:

**How do I extend my existing information about the current user to capture "last activity" so I can log him/her out if they haven't been using the site in a certain period of time?
Do I need to define a *custom user model*?**

**My next step after is to create a different type of user, so I feel like I need to make custom user models - beyond just extending the normal user form to make a profile etc.**

Thanks for your understanding,

I know I can be confusing when I don't understand things.

Thanks for your time,

James

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: Yeah I have. The more angles I can hear something explained, the more I actually understand what it is, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE) middleware for logging out the user automatically, 
configure the `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`, to some low value, and provide the `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST`, as `True`.

This will automatically logout the user after certain inactivity, without any need of extending the profile.

```
 SESSION_COOKIE_AGE
 Default: 1209600 (2 weeks, in seconds)
 >> The age of session cookies, in seconds.

 SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST
 Default: False
 >> Whether to save the session data on every request. 
 If this is False (default), then the session data will only be saved if it has been modified – that is, if any of its dictionary values have been assigned or deleted.
```

And for creating custom/extending `User` Profile, [Django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/), comes with [configurable User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#configurable-user-model), please check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#configurable-user-model) for examples.